# How to display a location depending on the value of an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Ive been learning C# in class and attempting to teach myself in my free time.

I am attempting to make my first game in C#. So far my code is:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string aValue;
        int Limit = 20;

        int[,] MOVEMENT = new int[20,20];           

        // MOVEMENT

        for (int i = 0; i < 20;)
            for (int j = 0; j < 20;)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Which direction do you wish to move in?");
                aValue = Console.ReadLine();

                // MOVE NORTH
                if (aValue == "North" || aValue == "north")
                {
                    i = i + 1;

                    if (i >= 20)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You cannot move any further in this direction!");
                        i = 20;
                    }
                }

                // MOVE SOUTH
                if (aValue == "South" || aValue == "south")
                {
                    i = i - 1;

                    if (i <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You cannot move any further in this direction!");
                        i = 0;
                    }
                }

                // MOVE EAST
                if (aValue == "East" || aValue == "east")
                {
                    j = j + 1;

                    if (j >= 20)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You cannot move any further in this direction!");
                        j = 20;
                    }
                }

                // MOVE WEST
                if (aValue == "West" || aValue == "west")
                {
                    j = j - 1;

                    if (j <= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("You cannot move any further in this direction!");
                        j = 0;
                    }
                }


                // Display where the character is after each movement and list possible events 
                // in the area. 

                Console.WriteLine("You are now at {0},{1}", i, j);


            }
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now want to make each Element of the array corresponde to a different location in the game. For example: 
        0,0 might be Home.
        0,1 might be Village. 
        0,2 might be Desert.
        1,5 might be Lake.

I want each location to have its own description and some events (Made with If statements and such).
Im unsure how to have the code display the location (Would this just be the value of the element?), depending on the i and j are equal too. 
I was told that a switch statement would be best to make this work but i've tried that and im not able to make it work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use objects?

```
public class Location{
    public int Latitude   {get;set;}
    public int Longitude  {get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Description  {get;set;}
}
```

and retrieve names and values with LINQ

```
yourIEnumerableLocation.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Latitude== yourXposition && x.Longitude == yourYposition)
```

or use Dictionnary as explains Gam Erix

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a [dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) of a struct and string (or struct of 2 strings - description and location respectively) where you would assign each location some info like this:

```
using System;
public struct Point
{
   public int x, y;

   public Point(int p1, int p2)
   {
      x = p1;
      y = p2;
   }
}
public struct Information
{
   public string description, location;

   public Information(string desc, string loc)
   {
      description = desc;
      location = loc;
   }
}
var info = new Dictionary<Point, Information>();

info[Point(i,j)] = Information("This is our lovely lake","Lake");
```